# IdentityServer3 symmetric key issue on Relying Party

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, ws-security, jwt, thinktecture-ident-server

I just set up a `SelfHost(InMem with WS-Fed)` **Thinktecture IdentityServer3** project example and I'm trying to use it to get a **JWT**, the problem is that I only recieve tokens signed with an asymmetric key using the alg `RS256` but I need them to be symmetric using the alg `HS256` so I can use the same key on the client.

I have tried to follow [some examples](http://blog.novanet.no/configuring-the-secure-token-signature-algorithm-in-thinktecture-identityserverv2-core/) by configuring the **Relying Party** on the server with no success.

For example, I see the following markup:

```
var relyingParty = new RelyingParty()
{
    Enabled = true,
    Realm = "urn:carbon",
    Name = "Test party",
    SymmetricSigningKey = 
      Convert.FromBase64String("R03W9kJERSSLH11Px+R/O7EYfAadSMQfZD5haQZj6eU="),
    TokenLifeTime = 120
};
```

But when I try it on my code, I have an error on `SymmetricSigningKey` and it says  that:

> 'Thinktecture.IdentityServer.WsFederation.Models.RelyingParty' does
>   not contain a definition for 'SymmetricSigningKey'

What am I doing wrong?, thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Markup of the startup file:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    var factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
        users: Users.Get(),
        clients: Clients.Get(),
        scopes: Scopes.Get()
    );

    var options = new IdentityServerOptions
    {
        IssuerUri = "https://idsrv3.com",
        SiteName = "Thinktecture IdentityServer3 - WsFed",

        SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
        Factory = factory,
        PluginConfiguration = ConfigurePlugins,

    };

    appBuilder.UseIdentityServer(options);
}

private void ConfigurePlugins(IAppBuilder pluginApp, IdentityServerOptions options)
{
    var wsFedOptions = new WsFederationPluginOptions(options);

    // data sources for in-memory services
    wsFedOptions.Factory.Register(new Registration<IEnumerable<RelyingParty>>(RelyingParties.Get()));
    wsFedOptions.Factory.RelyingPartyService = new Registration<IRelyingPartyService>(typeof(InMemoryRelyingPartyService));

    pluginApp.UseWsFederationPlugin(wsFedOptions);
}
```

Markup of the scope used:

```
new Scope
{
    Name = "api1"
}
```

Markup of the client used:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Silicon on behalf of Carbon Client",
    ClientId = "carbon",
    Enabled = true,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,

    Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
    ClientSecrets = new List<ClientSecret>
    {
        new ClientSecret("21B5F798-BE55-42BC-8AA8-0025B903DC3B".Sha256())
    }
}
```

Markup of the user used:

```
new InMemoryUser{Subject = "bob", Username = "bob", Password = "bob", 
    Claims = new Claim[]
    {
        new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Bob"),
        new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Smith"),
        new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, "BobSmith@email.com")
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just check the [class model](http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/wsFederation/relyingParties.html) of the relying party of IdentityServer3 and there's no property for the symmetric signing key... I'm lost...

Any ideas?

Comment: Just notice that the example you refer to is Identity server v2, could it be possible that you running old version example code on idsrv v3 package?